# ETSY API OAuth Issue

Tags: php, oauth, etsy

I have response correct first time going to Etsy page and allow access
but after getting response with

http://192.168.0.107/SAHL/ETSY/etsy.php?oauth_token=d751a108d6b1eb7a278ece3537a4a6&oauth_verifier=2420edbf

this URL then reload getting below error

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught OAuth\Common\Http\Exception\TokenResponseException: file_get_contents(https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/oauth/access_token): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized\r\n in /var/www/html/SAHL/ETSY/src/OAuth/Common/Http/Client/StreamClient.php:73\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/SAHL/ETSY/src/OAuth/OAuth1/Service/AbstractService.php(100): OAuth\Common\Http\Client\StreamClient->retrieveResponse(Object(OAuth\Common\Http\Uri\Uri), 'oauth_verifier=...', Array)\n#1 /var/www/html/SAHL/ETSY/etsy.php(52): OAuth\OAuth1\Service\AbstractService->requestAccessToken('d751a108d6b1eb7...', '2420edbf', 'f237e6c898')\n#2 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/SAHL/ETSY/src/OAuth/Common/Http/Client/StreamClient.php on line 73

```
$etsyService = $serviceFactory->createService('Etsy', $credentials, $storage);

if (!empty($_GET['oauth_token'])) {
    $token = $storage->retrieveAccessToken('Etsy');
    // This was a callback request from Etsy, get the token
    $etsyService->requestAccessToken(
        $_GET['oauth_token'],
        $_GET['oauth_verifier'],
        $token->getRequestTokenSecret()
    );

    // Send a request now that we have access token
    $result = json_decode($etsyService->request('/private/users/__SELF__'));
    echo 'result: <pre>' . print_r($result, true) . '</pre>';

    // $result_1 = json_decode($etsyService->request('/shops/SapphireDirect/listings/expired'));
    // echo 'result 1: <pre>' . print_r($result_1, true) . '</pre>';
} elseif (!empty($_GET['go']) && $_GET['go'] === 'go') {
    $response = $etsyService->requestRequestToken();
    $extra = $response->getExtraParams();
    $url = $extra['login_url'];
    header('Location: ' . $url);
} else {
    $url = $currentUri->getRelativeUri() . '?go=go';
    echo "<a href='$url'>Login with Etsy!</a>";
}
```